# How can I enable scrolling on a single item in Flex Layout?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-flex-layout

I'm using Angular CLI to create a flexbox page with 3 containers. The middle is attached to a route outlet and one has 2 items, left one showing a list and right one showing details when selecting an item from the list.
Here is what I'm coding

this is the app.component.html

```
<div class="container"
     fxLayout = "row" 
     fxLayoutAlign="center">
  <div class="item item-1" fxFlex="100%"><app-header></app-header>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container main"
     fxLayout = "column" 
     fxLayout.xs="column"
     fxLayoutAlign="center stretch"
     fxLayoutGap="10px"
     fxLayoutGap.xs="0">

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>


<div class="container"
     fxLayout
     fxLayout.xs="row"
     fxLayoutAlign="center"
     fxLayoutGap="10px"
     fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
  <div class="item item-1" fxFlex="100%"><app-messages></app-messages>
</div>
</div>
```

here's main-page.html

```
<div class="scrollable-item" fxFlex="25%">
<app-parts-list></app-parts-list> //here is the list to scroll
  </div>
  <div class="item" fxFlex="75%">
<app-part-details></app-part-details>
  </div>
```

here's app.component.css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
   min-height: 0;

}

.scrollable-item {
  overflow: auto;

}
```

I'm not familiar with CSS for sure as this is the first project I'm developing.
The issue is that I cannot get the scrollbar on scrollable-item div only, but I got it on the whole page as soon as the list gets populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a height for scrollable-item would bring the scroll only in that div.

```
.scrollable-item {
  height: 100px; // required height
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: That is the right answer, thanks anyway even if late, I may help others

Comment: @MaurizioSantovito Could you accept my answer if it solved your issue. Thank you!

Comment: what if you want the scrollable item to take the all screen ? Replacing height in your answer with `height: 100hv` is not working out

Comment: Fixed by adding 100% on body and main container div (mat-drawer-container): https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-material-seed-sjt6gg